# Chrome extension - update certain tab using tabId

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that when a user presses the icon it stores the current `tab.id` in a variable, and then after 2 minutes runs a `chrome.tabs.executeScript` function. As far as I can tell, my code should work but I get an error of:

`Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'tabId': Unexpected property`

[From the chrome developer site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update)

> **Update**
>
> `chrome.tabs.update(integer tabId, object updateProperties, function callback)`
>
> Modifies the properties of a tab.

Here is my code so far:

```
   //Up here is the logic for handling the icon press
   chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(arrayOfTabs) {

        var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0].id; //this is the active tab id.

            setInterval(function() { //Interval for every 2 minutes
                chrome.tabs.update({
                    tabId: activeTab, //this is where I get an error... What's wrong with this?
                    active: true,
                    url: "https://mywebsite.com/" + myarray[count]
                }, function(tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                        file: "function/jquery.min.js",
                        runAt: "document_end"
                    });

                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                        file: "function/code.js",
                        runAt: "document_end"
                    });

                })
                count++;
            }, timer);
    });
```

Any ideas on what's wrong with my code? I have tried `tabId: activeTab` as well as just `activeTab` but I keep getting an error. How can I specify to the `tabs.update` which tab I want to update? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
chrome.tabs.update(activeTab, {
  active: true,
  url: "https://mywebsite.com/" + myarray[count]
}, function(tab){});`
```

`tabId` and `updateProperties` are two different parameters.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thank you. I'll approve when it lets me.

Comment: @Katie, sorry but not much clear about your requirements. What do you mean "`tabs.update` is called that it doesn't take me away from my current tab"?

Comment: Nothing, I fixed the problem. I was confused about the `active: true` thing.